# can firebase server grouping User's device by Users's Setting?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, cron, google-cloud-functions

Hello I'm making some Weather info iOS application

I try to make Push Notification by Firebase

Is this possible to make? This is my Scenario

1. When user installed and launch app, they set the time when they want to get push notification
2. There are limited time options they can choose

   1. Everyday 8 a.m (Today's weather)
   2. Everyday 12 p.m (Today's weather)
   3. Everyday 10 p.m (Tomorrow's weather)
3. and i do cron job each for option by cron-job.org
4. if 'A', 'B' users set their time on 'Everyday 8 a.m',the result of cron job(Call API and send Data) send to 'A' and 'B'

I wonder is it possible when user set their time and that time is saved at server and Finally grouping User(Device) by time and send different data at different time Push Notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase supports `User segment` and `Topic`. For your scenario, you can create topic to each of your time option, and subscribe users to that topic respectively. Therefore, in your cron job script, you know which topic the user in and push notification to that topic. Please refer to this doc for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Comment: Oh i really looking forward this kind of things! Thanks a lot